# xBim.Essentials for Unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I was trying to use xBim to import ICF projects to Unity. 
So, I went to Visual Studios and in the part of Nuget Commands I wrote this:

```
PM> Install-Package Xbim.Essentials
```

I assume that it installed correctly for what I read, but does this allows me to work and import ICF projects to Unity through Visual Studios?

Thanks